# Color NavigationBar en iOS Xamarin.Forms, no me toma el color de una maner correcta

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, iphone

intento cambiar el color de mi NavigationBar en android, para en esta plataforma funciona correctamente, pero a la hora de cambiar el color en iOs el color de este me sale como degradado

NavigationBar en android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NavigationBar en iOs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL codigo que tengo para iOs en el archivo AppDelegate.cs es el siguiente:

````
 ``` UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

  UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Red;
  UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
  UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes()
  {
     ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
  }; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Desactivando la opción del traslúcido en el Storyboard o por código:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```